# Feynman rules for scalar electrodynamics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, propagator, wick-theorem

### The issue

I have been learning perturbation theory in QFT, but due to the weird nature of the course I was attending I still haven't learned how to properly do it by Feynman diagrams. I think the best way to learn is to introduce an example I have worked out to let you see how I'm doing things, in the hope that someone can explain to me how to use Feynman diagrams to simplify the whole thing.

### A calculation by Wick contractions

As far as I know (please correct me if I am wrong), in order to write down the Feynman diagrams one only really needs two things: knowledge of the interaction Lagrangian, and of the $|\text{IN}\rangle$ and $|\text{OUT}\rangle$ Fock states. So let me consider a specific example from scalar electrodynamics, described by the interaction action
$$ S_I=\int d^4x\Big(-ieA_\mu\phi^*\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial^\mu}\phi+e^2 A_\mu A^\mu\phi^*\phi\Big) $$
(The double arrow really means that the derivatives are acting on both sides as $\phi^*\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial^\mu}\phi=\phi^*\partial^\mu\phi-\partial^\mu\phi^*\phi$).

In particular, consider the Compton scattering $\pi^++\gamma\to\pi^++\gamma$. The associated initial and final states are
$$|\text{IN}\rangle=a_+^\dagger(\mathbf{p_1})c^\dagger(\mathbf{k_1},\lambda_1)|0\rangle, \quad |\text{OUT}\rangle=\langle 0|a_+(\mathbf{p_2})c(\mathbf{k_2},\lambda_2). $$
We now look at the formal  expansion of $S_I$ in powers of $e$: the identity, as always does not count. The linear term $e A_\mu\phi^*\partial^\mu\phi$ contains three fields, not enough to contract all four Fock operators, and thus does not contribute. The quadratic term $e^2 A_\mu A^\mu\phi^*\phi$ is the first good candidate to be non-zero, but to keep gauge invariance we need to look at all other terms with the same power of $e$, which include
$$ e^2\int  A_\mu(x)\phi^*(x)\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial^\mu}\phi(x)\int A_\nu(y)\phi^*(y)\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial^\mu}\phi(y), $$
so the amplitude will be the sum of these terms. For example, the latter gives the contribution
\begin{align}
a_1=\langle 0| a_+(\mathbf p_2) c(\mathbf k_2,\lambda_2)(ie)^2 \Big(T[A_\mu(x)\phi(x)\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial^\mu}\phi^*(x)A_\nu(y)\phi(y)(\partial^\nu)^\leftrightarrow\phi^*(y)]\Big) a_+^\dagger(\mathbf p_1) c^\dagger(\mathbf k_1,\lambda_1)|0\rangle
\end{align}
which I can calculate using Wick contractions. The first contraction
$$ \overbrace{c(\mathbf k_2,\lambda_2) A_\mu(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2|\mathbf k_2|}}\frac{e^{ik_2x}}{\sqrt V}\epsilon_\mu^*(\mathbf k_2,\lambda_2) $$ can occur in two different ways, as there are two fields $A_\mu(x), A_\nu(y)$ containing the operator $c^\dagger$. But as there is symmetry in $x$ and $y$, we can just contract one field and write a factor of $2$. The remaining field is then contracted with $c^\dagger$, giving
$$ \overbrace{ A_\nu(y) c^\dagger(\mathbf k_1,\lambda_1) }\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2|\mathbf k_1|}}\frac{e^{-ik_1x}}{\sqrt V}\epsilon_\mu(\mathbf k_2,\lambda_2). $$ These wave functions break the symmetry in the position coordinates, so when contracting $a_+$ we need to keep both possibilities. Lastly, by Lorentz invariance of the empty state $a_+^\dagger$ can only contract with the $\phi$ field uncoupled to the one already contracted. Finally, we have to take care of the propagators:
$$ \langle 0|T[\phi(x)\phi^*(y)]|0\rangle=i\int\frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{-iq(x-y)}}{q^2-m^2},
        \quad
        \langle 0|T[\phi^*(x)\phi(y)]|0\rangle=i\int\frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{e^{-iq(y-x)}}{q^2-m^2}. $$
So substituting every possible contraction with the caveats that I have specified we obtain the expression
\begin{align}
a_1=\frac{ie^2}{4V^2\sqrt{E_{p_1}E_{p_2}E_{k_1}E_{k_2}}} \int\frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{q^2-m^2}\epsilon_\mu^*(\mathbf k_2,\lambda_2)\epsilon_\nu(\mathbf k_1,\lambda_1)\Big(&\int d^4xd^4y e^{ik_2x}e^{-ik_1y}e^{-ip_1x}(\partial_x^\mu)^\leftrightarrow e^{-iq(x-y)}(\partial_y^\nu)^\leftrightarrow e^{ip_2 y} +\int d^4xd^4y e^{ik_2x}e^{-ik_1y}e^{-iqx}(\partial_x^\mu)^\leftrightarrow e^{ip_2x}e^{-ip_1y}(\partial_y^\nu)^\leftrightarrow e^{iqy}\Big)
\end{align}
which we can solve to obtain $a_1$ explicitly.

### Feynman diagrams

Doing this whole business of Wick contractions gets old pretty quickly. I've read that Feynman diagrams simplify these calculations considerably, but I can't find good notes with decent examples online. So I turn to you on SE with a this question: how do I draw the Feynman diagrams for this problem, and what exactly are the rules to compute them?

Comment: Have you already consulted some "standard" texbook like the one of Mark Srednicki, or Peskin & Schroeder? For the scalar QED try with this: https://canvas.harvard.edu/files/936391/download?download_frd=1&verifier=x0zyaPHMxOvHCcrRCDqlHUqjT4stQ3tv0Z69Eohc

Comment: Whelp, my question has been closed. Is "how do I write the Feynman diagrams for Compton scattering" such an unfocused question? @Quillo, I see that those notes have been written by Schwartz. I should have access to his book, I'll check it later and see if I can understand something.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, "how do I write the Feynman diagrams for Compton scattering" is a legit question I think, but the title says "rules" (and rules are much more general: there are diagrams that are specific for a certain process, at a certain order, but rules are the same for every scattering process). You can try to make it more specific (i.e. just about Compton) and it will be reopened (I think).

Comment: @Quillo The point is that I don't know much about this topic in general, so I have a hard time formulating the question appropriately. Now that you tell me that rules are generic but diagrams are specific I have something to go on about at least. I've checked Schwartz, and there is a chapter called "Feynman rules" that I will read as soon as I've got the time.